# How to drag an uiimageview without overlapping views?

Tags: ios, drag-and-drop, uiimageview

I have more than one view in superview. How can i drag an uiimageview without overlapping or touching other views. Any help is appreciated..

Comment: Did you meant using an interface builder to drag and drop? using .xib? or storyboard?

Comment: maybe you can see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11650149/drag-able-button-in-ios-iphone-such-that-it-repositions-itself-in-its-orignal-po/11651212#11651212

Comment: no danny, i have added two imageview in superview. i just need to drag one imageview without touching/overlapping other..

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented similar type of thing. Here I am posting code snippet.
Draggable is class which you need to import in other class which contain images.

1) Draggable.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Draggable : UIImageView
{
    CGPoint startLocation;
}
@end
```

2) Draggable.m

```
#import "Draggable.h"

@implementation Draggable

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
    // Retrieve the touch point
    CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    startLocation = pt;
    [[self superview] bringSubviewToFront:self];
}
- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
    // Move relative to the original touch point
    CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    CGRect frame = [self frame];
    frame.origin.x += pt.x - startLocation.x;
    frame.origin.y += pt.y - startLocation.y;
    [self setFrame:frame];
}

@end
```

3) ProfilePicViewController.m - my class with images

```
#import "Draggable.h"

UIImageView *dragger;

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    UIImage *tmpImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"];

    CGRect cellRectangle;
    cellRectangle = CGRectMake(0,0,tmpImage.size.width ,tmpImage.size.height );
    dragger = [[Draggable alloc] initWithFrame:cellRectangle];
    [dragger setImage:tmpImage];
    [dragger setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    [self.view addSubview:dragger];

}
```

here you can drag "dragger" on other images. Make sure to have proper image size. size of icon.png is 48X48. So just have image size that fits into your screen.

Hope this can help you bit.